# Very High Spike and Unusual MOSFET Gate Switching Signal

Tags: mosfet, driver

My apology if I describe something wrong in this question, English is not my native language. I've been trying to work on a bidirectional converter simulation, but there are a few problem I met with the circuit mostly the switching signal of the MOSFET gate.

In the second picture (yellow graph) is the gate signal of the P-channel MOSFET, I've tried the snubber network and a resistor to pull the MOSFET gate to ground but the signal remain the same.

Do you have any suggestion on how I could improve the gate signal, I would really appreciated

[image: The Schematic of Bidirectional Converter (LTSpice)]
[image: PWM Signal and the Signal to NMOS and PMOS]

Comment: Welcome! Please name the nodes as one needs to guess which is V(n001) and V(n006). If you are using custom models, it is possible to have MOSFET symbols in the schematic in LTspice as opposed to the magic box. Are you using the auto generated symbol function from the .subckt file?

Comment: Try using a series gate resistor of about 10 ~ 20 Ohms.

Comment: @winny Yes, I use the auto generated from .subckt file I downloaded from Mouser, the V(n001) is the Gate pin of SUP70101EL and V(n006) is the Gate pin of the IRFB4310Z(1 = Drain, 2 = Gate, 3 = Source)

Comment: Please name the nodes to make it easier for the readers to having to looks though the comments to find what’s what.

Comment: @F.Heisenberg I tried as you suggested, but the signal don't look any different

Comment: @winny Sorry, I'm new to the software. But I already edited as you suggested. Could you help me identify the problem?

Comment: There's no dead-time, you have shoot-through.

Comment: @JonathanS. So that's why there are spikes, but how do I add a dead-time to this simulation?

Comment: Much better! Unless your IRS MOSFET driver provides any, you need to disconnect your short between INA and INB and provide external dead-time.

Comment: Thanks @winny I tried to solve this simulation issues about a week now, but do you have any MOSFET driver suggestion? For the last time I use the IR2184 (on actual hardware) but it fried 8 MOSFETs, and now I try this IRS4427S but I think if I apply to real hardware it might not get any better

Comment: With cross conduction, no wonder. There are drivers with built-in dead time, but it’s more flexible to do it yourself if it’s fixed. What’s your PWM source in the first place?

Comment: @winny No it's not a fixed on-time, the duty cycle changes since it will be used in a closed-loop control

Comment: I never asked about fixed on-time. Let me rephrase, _what_ is providing the PWM, an MCU, a PWM controller or something else?

Comment: I use the STM32 as the PWM generator (Closed-loop controller), and the coding for the STM32 is done in Simulink

Comment: Excellent, then you can use one more output from it an implement your dead-band time in code at no extra cost.

Comment: @winny Thank you so much! I never know I can do that. But Now I don't know how to do that yet, I'll look into it. I'll let you know the result as I'm doing it. Thank you again